# IPv6 Compatibility Issues with Low-Level C API's

Tags: objective-c, c, sockets

Apple requires IPv6 Compatibility. Seems a little premature, but I suppose someone has to force it's wide adoption.

I have a client who has some legacy code that will no longer be approved for the App Store because of this incompatibility. I did not write the software by myself, and specifically have never touched this part of the code. I am not much of a ninja when it comes to low-level C networking.

I told the client that part of the problem was that they had an IPv4-only server and had us hardcode an IPv4 address to that server. I updated the IPv4 address to a domain name and told them their servers had to support IPv6. So, they moved them all over, and flipped the switch before any testing could be done. I was notified a few days ago that all their software on the store no longer worked. That's the predicament we are in.

Here is one of potentially many issues that I could use some help on.

Not only does the server that is connected to the port not respond to IPv6, but there are some lower level APIs that are being used that are incompatible.

The first thing I encountered is the use of `gethostbyname()`. Apparently this is not IPv6 capable. I have been trying to fix it with `getaddrinfo()` but my sockaddr's are not quite the same.

The second issue I can see is that apparently I need to be using `AF_UNSPEC` instead of `AF_INET`. So I am attempting to open a socket in the following way:

```
int sockfd = socket(AF_UNSPEC, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
```

I always get -1.

If I open a sock using `AF_INET` I get further, but then I have this issues:

```
otherAddr   sockaddr *  0x618000220680  0x0000618000220680
   sa_len   __uint8_t   '\x1c'
   sa_family    sa_family_t '\x1e'
   sa_data  char [14]   "\x13\x88"  
otherAddrCast   sockaddr *  0x7000052d3c28  0x00007000052d3c28
   sa_len   __uint8_t   '\0'
   sa_family    sa_family_t '\0'
   sa_data  char [14]   "\x13\x88\"Ԛ\\"
```

So some of the `sa_data` is the same. and if I don't cast the `sockaddr_in` to a `struct sockaddr*` then the `sa_data` is the same.

Problem is I don't know what most of this means. Help?

EDIT: Here is my code. Assume that I am only getting 1 addr back (because I am)

```
    struct hostent* server = gethostbyname([_hostname UTF8String]);
    struct addrinfo *ai;
    struct addrinfo hints;


    memset(&hints, 0x00, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family   = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

    NSString* portString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", _port];
    getaddrinfo([_hostname UTF8String], [portString cStringUsingEncoding:kCFStringEncodingASCII] , &hints, &ai);

    struct sockaddr_in addr = {0};
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    bcopy(server->h_addr, &addr.sin_addr.s_addr, server->h_length);
    addr.sin_port = htons(_port);
    int sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    _addr = (struct sockaddr*)&addr;
    int status = connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr));
    int status2 = connect(socket(ai->ai_family,ai->ai_socktype,0), ai->ai_addr, ai->ai_addrlen);
```

Comment: You probably need to find an IPv6 socket tutorial. The question is maybe a little broad for stackoverflow.

Comment: "Seems a little premature" - Yes, it is only that IPv4 has just ran out of addresses and IPv6 is about only 20 years standardised. Absolutely prematurely ...

Comment: I found http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html very helpful

Comment: I understand that the standard has been around, unfortunately that is not enough. Many consumer ISP's ( the majority of app users ) do not support IPv6 completely. This creates quite a bit of challenge to people trying to support it without a reasonable path for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are NOT supposed to use `AF_UNSPEC` with `socket()` at all. You MUST use either `AF_INET` (IPv4) or `AF_INET6` (IPv6).

You can use `AF_UNSPEC` with the `hints` input parameter of `getaddrinfo()` to indicate that you are willing to accept both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses as output. The actual addresses in the output will be either `AF_INET` or `AF_INET6`.  Or, you can set the hints to `AF_INET` for IPv4-only output. Or `AF_INET6` for IPv6-only output.

You are supposed to loop through the list that is returned by `getaddrinfo()`. For each address in the list:

- pass its `ai_family`,  `ai_socktype`, and `ai_protocol` fields to `socket()`
- then pass its `ai_addr` and `ai_addrlen` fields to `bind()` (servers) or `connect()` (clients).

Repeat this for all addresses reported for a listening server, and for all addresses reported for a client until one successfully connects.

This way, each socket you create matches the IP version of the address it is working with, and you are passing an appropriate matching `sockaddr_in` (IPv4) or `sockaddr_in6` (IPv6) to `bind()`/`connect()`.

Once you have successful listening server socket(s), or a successfully connected client socket, if you need to retrieve an IP from a socket using `accept()`, `getsockname()` or `getpeername()`, be sure to pass it a `sockaddr_storage` struct to fill in. `sockaddr_storage` is large enough to hold all defined `sockaddr`-based structures (and there are many).  If successful, you can then type-cast it to a `sockaddr_in` or `sockaddr_in6` based on its `sa_family` field (`AF_INET` or `AF_INET6`, respectively). Same goes for other similar functions, like `inet_pton()` and `inet_ntop()`.

---

**Update**: given the client code you have shown, try this instead:

```
struct addrinfo hints = {0};
hints.ai_family   = AF_INET;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

NSString* portString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", _port];

struct addrinfo *ai;
int sockfd = -1;

int status = getaddrinfo([_hostname UTF8String], [portString cStringUsingEncoding:kCFStringEncodingASCII] , &hints, &ai);
if (status == 0) {
    sockfd = socket(ai->ai_family, ai->ai_socktype, ai->ai_protocol);
    if (sockfd == -1) {
        status = errno;
    }
    else if (connect(sockfd, ai->ai_addr, ai->ai_addrlen) < 0) {
        status = errno;
        close(sockfd);
        sockfd = -1;
    }
    freeaddrinfo(ai);
}

if (sockfd == -1) {
    // handle status error as needed...
}
else {
    // use sockfd as needed...
    close(sockfd);
}
```

Comment: Downvoter, please explain why you downvote.

Comment: thank you for answering my question. I rarely deal with any low level API's. I appreciate that you took the time to understand that despite the question I had little way to refine it further due to inexperience in these libraries. You took the time to explain what didn't make sense about the way I was using constants and types while others just marked it as too broad. Again, thank you.

Comment: I am getting further with this, unfortunately I cannot tell why my resulting connections are different. See edit above

Comment: @Xials: Define "*resulting connections are different*" exactly. You have two sockets and two connections. What is "different" about them? In any case, you are not checking the result of `gethostbyname()` for error before using it. Why are you calling `gethostbyname()`? Get rid of it. You are also not checking the result of `getaddrinfo()` for error before using it. Also, get rid of your `sockaddr_in addr` variable, you don't need it. Use the `ai_addr` that is provided by `getaddrinfo()`. And why are you calling `connect()` twice at all?

Comment: @Xials: The two `connect()` calls you have shown are logically identical from a data handling perspective (assuming no errors are being reported), so the only difference between them would have to be in the IP address returned by `gethostbyname()` vs the IP address returned by `getaddrinfo()`. Both functions can return multiple IPs, in any order, and your shown code is not accounting for that possibility.

Comment: Thanks Remy. The I am tasked with repairing this code in order to allow it to work on IPv6. I am trying to get rid of gethostbyname() but it works (except on IPv6), and getaddrinfo() does not. I actually tried the code above, as well as iterating through the 4 address returned from getaddrinfo() when I use AF_UNSPEC (or 2 when I specify SOCK_STREAM)  So the question is what else could cause it to not be the same? could it be a server issue?

Comment: @Xials: I assure you that `getaddrinfo()` works when used correctly. You are not using it correctly.

Comment: I don’t doubt that it does. But I’m unsure what is wrong. I created a recursive method to attempt to connect to every address returned. Still nothing. It is returning addresses, but it is connect that fails when I use the data returned from getaddrinfo().